# Navigate with the arrow keys within a text in console with Nasm in Linux

Tags: linux, text, assembly, console, nasm

I'm working on a proyect which is divided in two parts. The firs one is some kind of text visualizer (in the console) wich involves thatthe user can navigate within the text with the arrow keys.

now, i dont have even a clue of how can i solve this, the biggest thing i've done in nasm was a regular expresion analizer, that's all. i imagine that i should display the text but at the end, not give back the control to the OS. the bottom 3 lines,

```
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0 
int 80h
```

so then i can start capturing the arrow keys. so, if the user press the up arrow key, a pointer moves 80 spaces back in the buffer that contains the text and so on with the rest of the keys. (thats for editing)

i really dont know if this is even possible, but any recomendation or advice or a link to where i can investigate a littlr bit more would be awesome!

Comment: Don't do that in assembly code.

Comment: Have you checked ncurses? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Comment: haha I need to, it's a final proyect for a class

Answer (score 1):

I have no UNIX assembler experience but you may use ncurses (or maybe simpler to restrict you to VT-100 terminals, surely you will never meet anything incompatible).
Here are VT-100 control codes: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php. Set canonical mode with `stty -icanon`. Read from console using a conventional fread(stdin) and recognize arrow keycodes:

```
up      EscA    EscOA
down    EscB    EscOB 
right   EscC    EscOC
left    EscD    EscOD.
```

Then use escape sequences to clean screen and draw the new image - it will be a pretty hardcode, but this so is assembler.